# How to use operamail from behind a proxy?

Tags: email, gmail, opera

2 cases here:
- at home, I can use operamail to fetch email from... let's say gmail's IMAP server 
- at work, I'm behind a proxy, and when I tried to use operamail to fetch emails, it failed with the generic message 'The connection with the IMAP server was unexpectedly interrupted.'

So, can operamail work from behind a proxy?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 4):

Opera Mail normally uses the same proxy as defined in preferences, for the whole program.

Fact is, in some firms, only some ports are available through the proxy. If you can't use the imap port (you can try with another mail client program, like Thunderbird), then it won't work either in Opera Mail.

Answer (score 3):

The IMAP ports have most likely been blocked on the corporate network. External mail access is frowned upon by a lot of companies since it does pose a security risk.

Comment: Though most of times, access to webmails is possible, so about security...

Comment: I wish it was the case at work. We have everything blocked, even blogs and RSS feed readers.

Comment: Ouch. (though it has to be somehow increasing productivity. I guess)

Comment: Well I did get SU and SO unblocked so I am more then happy with the arrangement :)

Comment: Of course they unblocked it as "source of answers for technical problems", I guess, not as "I'm a moderator there" :]